# fsockopen не отправляет данные без fgets

Tags: php

Попытка асинхронно отправить данные с помощью `fsockopen()` не проходит. В чем может быть проблема? Отправляет только если поставить `die` перед `fclose()`. Или если добавить вывод результата с помощью `fgets()` но тогда запрос уже перестает быть асинхронным.

```
if (!$open = fsockopen(site.ru, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30)) 
return false;

fwrite($open, "POST /script.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
fwrite($open, "Host: site.ru\r\n"); 
fwrite($open, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
fwrite($open, "Content-Length: 6\r\n"); 
fwrite($open, "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"); 
fwrite($open, "params=1"); 
fclose($open);
```

Comment: Если не сложно, добавьте пример кода, при помощи которого отправляете запрос?

Comment: @cheops добавил